# Is there a way to let Mail always mark the messages coming from a domain as spam?

Tags: mail.app, email, spam

I keep getting emails from a domain, which always use the same email address; every time I mark them as junk in Mail, but Mail keeps showing those email in my inbox.

Is there a way to force Mail to consider those emails as junk? Do those emails contain a header that forces Mail to consider them acceptable messages? As far as I can see, I only have the problem with those emails; other emails that I mark as junk are never shown again in the inbox.

The emails I receive are not in my Google Mail account.

**Update:** Mail allows to set some custom actions for junk mail. I forgot to say I edited those settings to be as in the following screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

I simply added the last condition to the default ones used by Mail, to avoid messages coming from Drupal.org would be moved to the spam folder (it can happened that I receive messages about spam on Drupal.org, as I am a site maintainer there). As the condition before the one I added is "Message is Junk Mail," and as the spammy address is not in my address book, it not in my previous recipients, and I have already marked the email as junk, I would expect the emails to be marked as spam, always.

In the "Junk Mail" tab, those custom actions are enabled.

[image: screenshot]

Still, even after I changed the settings for junk mail, I am getting those junk messages as if they were normal messages. This means that, having changed the settings didn't help, or make things worse.

Comment: Don't you simply want to mark email as spam from a specific domain? I find your applied rule a bit too bloated. It's prone to mistakes because you chose "if all conditions are met". I would try using a rule that only contains ``from``+``contains``+``@xxxx`` in the conditions.

Comment: The conditions I show in the screenshots are the ones I have already applied more than one month ago, as I was missing reports about spam I could have removed from drupal.org. The conditions are the default ones, to which I added the one not to consider messages from Drupal.org as spam. Even before I enabled the custom actions, the messages I received from the spammy domain were considered not junk.

Comment: I do not mean that you have to remove the other definitions. Just leave the default one as it is and create a whole new rule. The default rule must have some problem already, since it is **only applied when the Message is Junk Mail - which it is not** for some reason, since it still appears in the inbox.

Comment: The option that was enabled before was "Move it to the Junk mailbox" which means no custom actions were done. That is why I am asking if the email is set to appear as not junk using some headers. Of all the spam, I have only problems with that email address; the other spam is detected, and moved to the junk mailbox.

Comment: Why is drupal.org in parentheses ? try without

Comment: Because the "From" header contains that between parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

Mail.app has a feature called **rules** that enables you to automate your mail tasks.

You can define rules in the Mail preferences.
[image]